# How to get a number of rows for given query?

Tags: scala, count, scalaquery

I would like to get a **number** (like 5, 1000, etc.) of rows for given query. However method "count" for query gives me ColumnOps.CountAll -- and I don't know how to get the **number**.

See SQ wiki for example:
https://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/wiki/Counts

```
(for(...) yield ...).count
```

Obviously one step is missing, and the question is -- what is that step?

*I use explicit query route because the count is for join.*

Answer (score 1):

You can get a number to do like this:

```
val q = (for(...) yield ...).count
q.first
```

I was confused by ScalaQuery document too.
I recommend that you check SQ's tests to know how it use.

Comment: Thank you, but I still got error "value first is not a member of org.scalaquery.ql.ColumnOps.CountAll".